# Eclipse Run As doesn't show Junit or testNG option

Tags: eclipse, testng, junit4

I am trying to execute a simple test case using Junit4 in Eclipse (version 3.7.0)

1) I click on the Run icon (next to the debug icon), then click on the Run As option, it only shows Java Application as an option 
2) when I click on Run Configuration option, within the Create, Manage and run configuration window, I saw Junit and TestNG listed in the left pane

3)click on Window>show views>I can see Junit and TestNG listed as an option

Please advise me how to resolve this issue. Thanks!

**Project Name: webDriverMethods**

below is my code

```
import org.junit.*; 
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import org.testng.annotations.Test; //added 5 imports for Junit and testNG

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class webDriverMethodsTest 
{
  @Test
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add `@Test` on a static method with arguments, it will be ignored. This could possibly work with TestNG if you define a data provider but it's most likely not what you want. Test methods are regular methods on the class, see http://testng.org for examples.

Comment: Hello Cedric that for the advise. I modified the code by adding these lines: 1) **import org.junit.Test**, comments out testNG's Test annotation; 2) removed **static** keyword in the main method, took out the the argument in the main method, then give method a different name. 3) click on Run As the Junit test option displayed + code worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Does you add Testng and Junit .Jar file in your current project, if you add TestNG and Junit jar file in your project then you can run your project with testng and Junit

you check [`here`](http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html) how to install Testng in Ecplise

You can download Junit form [Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/junit/files/junit/3.8.1/junit3.8.1.zip/download?use_mirror=kaz&download=) after download import jar file in ecplise and then check

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a method annotated with @Test for the plugins to recognize it as a TestNG test.  Add an import of the testng test annotation to see run as-> TestNG as an option or impprt @Test from junit to see run as -> Junit, TestNG as an option.

Comment: I added 5 imports as your suggested. I can see testNG from the Run As section, but Junit is not displayed as an option. Please check by code section and advise me what shall I do. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the advise, I modify the code it worked as a Junit test.